# Maximum number of fields for Python .format

Tags: python, string, format, range, tuples

I'm constructing a pretty long mysql query using the Python string.format() method.  However, when I try to use more than 10 fields ({0} to {10}) I get a tuple out of range error.  When I only use 10 fields ({0} to {9}), there's no problem.

I really just need to know how many fields .format() can handle and how to address a field over #9 if it's possible.  Thank you!

Comment: you realise that 11 is not 10 yes? Do you actually have 11 eleven values?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't really a limit to the number of placeholders you can use; if you get an index error you have *miscounted* the number of elements you are formatting in. `{10}` otherwise works just fine:

```
>>> '{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5} {6} {7} {8} {9} {10}'.format(*range(11))
'0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10'
```

Take into account that since counting starts at *zero*, there are *eleven* elements there.

You should not, however, be using `str.format()` to produce SQL queries. Use SQL parameters instead, to ensure proper quoting (preventing SQL injection security holes), and allow for the database to re-use the query plan of your queries.

Answer (score 1):

It can take as many that you can put into the string. There was an error with your logic:

> when I try to use more than 10 fields ({0} to {10}) I get a tuple out of range error.

That's because you have 11 things to add, when you only supply 10. Tuples start from 0, so a ten item tuple would only be...

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 # Count! That's 10 items!
```

That's why when you did `{0} to {9}`, you don't get an error.